# How not to override existing files with R

Tags: r, save

If I want to save an R-object `a <- 1` to be saved under the  `filename <- "a.rda"`, but only if such an a.rda file doesn't exist, is there a shorter solution to `if(!filename %in% dir()) save(a, file = filename)`? Something like `save(a, file = filename, override = FALSE)`? (The same would be useful for `write.table()`, or `pdf()`.)

Comment: Is `if(!filename %in% dir())` really that much of an inconvenience? Also, I think `if (!file.exists(filename))` would be more robust.

Comment: Thank you @nrussell for showing me `file.exists`. In general I would appreciate a possibilty in those functions to let them be careful.

Comment: You can write your own version of these functions that take `override` as an additional argument.